# How to write a plugin or userscript to pop out an embedded YouTube video to a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, html5-fullscreen

## Author's notes

I think I can implement it by myself after being inspired by comments. Thank you for stopping by.

## Original question

For example, I want to pop out the embedded YouTube video in page

https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud037/l-1649018590/m-1659588540

It looks like this

[image: Imgur]

The youtube html5 player is embedded as an iframe

```
<iframe data-ng-controller="videoPlayer" class="ng-scope" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="930" height="523" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OATi2nCjEoE?autoplay=1&amp;color=red&amp;controls=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;fs=1&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;html5=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udacity.com" id="widget2"></iframe>
```

I wish that the player could be popped out in a new window with URL:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/OATi2nCjEoE?autoplay=1&color=red&controls=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&fs=1&theme=light&wmode=opaque&html5=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udacity.com

[image: Imgur]

Thanks to JaromandaX, my temporary script is as following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @include        https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      setTimeout(function(){

                          var button = document.createElement('button');
                          button.type = 'button';
                          button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Pop Youtube'));
                          button.setAttribute("onclick", "window.open(document.getElementById('widget2').src, 'my video');")
                          document.querySelectorAll("[class=row-gap-small]")[0].appendChild(button)
                      }, 2000);
                  });
```

[image: Imgur]

My problem is that after switching the youtube player's contents through buttons as illustrated in the image, the iframe `src` doesn't change. Thus clicking the button still takes me to the previous lesson's youtube player.

Comment: an extension (firefox/chrome) or userscript (greasemonkey/tampermonkey) would be able to do what you need. Wouldn't know how to do it with IE or Edge - apparently Edge will get some extension goodness, but last I heard, it's "coming", not "here" yet

Comment: @JaromandaX I exactly would like to accomplish this through an extension or userscript in Chrome

Comment: I would recommend starting with tampermonkey, then, once you're happy with the code, convert it to an extension if you want. This is how I sometimes deal with firefox extensions. However, I'm not familiar with chrome extensions, so, not sure how easy it is to port userscripts to chrome extension (it's quite simple with greasemonkey -> firefox extension)

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried to access the iframe to get the `src` with JavaScript, but it says that I am not allowed to do so because of the same origin policy

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem at all, because the iframe is an element of your document, I would think that as the src attribute is just a string, there's no domain issues at all. Perhaps you can show some (minimal) code that behaves as you say

Comment: @JaromandaX I run in the console ``$("#widget2").contents().find("body").html()`` it says ``Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.udacity.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.``

Comment: well, that's not getting the src from the iframe

Comment: @JaromandaX then how to get the ``src``?

Comment: I have no idea as I can't see the page you're working with - perhaps `document.getElementById("widget2").src`

Comment: Oh, wait, you want the src of something INSIDE the iframe - that's going to need some fancy coding where you inject javascript in both the main page and the iframe using your userscript (or extension) and have those scripts communicate with each other - at least, I think that's your only hope

Comment: @JaromandaX it works, thanks. What is the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: mine gets the src attribute of the iframe, you're trying to get the actual html inside the iframe

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var ytVideoSrc = false;
$('.ng-scope').each(function () { // class may exist multiple time

    if ( $(this).data('ng-controller') == 'videoPlayer' ) // search for first player
    {
      ytVideoSrc = $(this).attr('src); // grab src and stop loop
      return false;
    }

});

if ( ytVideoSrc ) // src found, open pop-up
    window.open(ytVideoSrc, "my video"); // open new window with src.
```

**EDIT**

in order to prevent the player from starting automatically, just modify the `autoplay` parameter in that URL:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/OATi2nCjEoE?**autoplay=1**&color=red&controls=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&fs=1&theme=light&wmode=opaque&html5=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udacity.com

```
 ytVideoSrc = ytVideoSrc.replace('autoplay=1', 'autoplay=0');
```

In order to understand how to integrate a YT player, you may have a look here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en

Comment: Yours doesn't work for me. I have updated my temporary script. I have a problem that the player seems to be injected into the page. I have to wait 2 seconds after the page is ready to find the `src`. I am also looking for ways to prevent the embedded player from autoplay.

Comment: You **should not grab the content**  but search **the YT URL** and leave the rest up to the __embed__ parameter in that URL

Comment: I think I have made significant progress. But my new problem is that the contents of the youtube player could be changed without changing the `src` of the player. Please look at my updated problem. Thanks!